# CakePhp 3 strange behavior AuthComponent

Tags: php, google-chrome, authentication, cakephp-3.0

**Environment:**
php 5.4.45
CakePhp 3.1.11
Debian 7

**Problem**
Login is not alway's working. After submit it returns the same login-page without error. After closing and restarting the browser, the login works as expected.
The problem seems to exist mostley with Google Chrome.
Some clients (on Mac and Google Chrome) are -even after closing and restarting- never able to login. On the same machine it does work with Safari and FireFox.

On my testserver (Debian 8, php 5.6, Cake 3.3) I never experienced this problem. But than again, since it is a test-server, It is not used on a lot of machines.

**UserControler** login

```
public function login()
{

    $session = $this->request->session();
    $session->destroy();
    $session->renew();
    Cache::clear(false);
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ID_start');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {


        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($user) {
            $newtime = date("Ymd|H:i:s");
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $this->loadModel('Teams');
            $team = $this->Teams->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
            $team['tijd'] = $newtime;
            $this->Teams->save($team);

            $enter = hash('md2', $newtime);
            $session_id = session_id();
            $session->write('naam', $team['naam']);
            $session->write('initialen', $team['initialen']);
            $session->write('vol_naam', $team['vol_naam']);
            $session->write('team_ID', $team['id']);
            $session->write('pass', md5($team['pass']));
            $session->write('code', $team['code']);
            $session->write('enter', $enter);
            $session->write('session', $session_id);

            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'start']);

        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

enter code here
```

As you can see, I try to kill all possible existing sessions and cache before start.

**So my questions are:** Is this behavior a consequence of the environement? And should I update it in order to fix it? What does Chrome do to make this login fale?
Or am I making some other mistake I'm not aware of.